# How to reposition lightslider.js controls outside of the main carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

By default, the slider controls are positioned inside the main carousel div (top line in attached image). I want the controls to be separately positioned so they don't appear on top of the images (bottom line in attached image).

I can see the relevant code on line 186 of the [lightslider.js](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightslider/blob/master/src/js/lightslider.js) file that places & positions the carousel controls but I don't know what I'd have to change to position the controls outside of the main carousel div.

[image]

Comment: Can your create a problem `fiddle`. I sense issue would be with your other `CSS`..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you have to remove the default next/prev buttons by passing `controls: false`. 
Then create your own next/prev buttons and use public methods (`goToPrevSlide()` , `goToNextSlide()`) to translate the slider to next and previous slides respectively.

**Html**

```
<ul id="lightSlider">
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-1.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li data-thumb="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/thumb/cS-2.jpg">
        <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/img/cS-2.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="goToPrevSlide">Prev</button>
<button type="button" id="goToNextSlide">Next</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var slider = $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
    controls: false
});
$('#goToPrevSlide').on('click', function () {
    slider.goToPrevSlide();
});
$('#goToNextSlide').on('click', function () {
    slider.goToNextSlide();
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2patspw2/1519/

Answer (score 4):

Simply we can override the Lightslider plugin CSS to :

```
.lSSlideOuter {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

and override the position relative to static of .lSSlideWrapper.

```
.lSSlideWrapper {
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving the controls section outside the `.LSSliderOuter` section bu using this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.lSAction').insertBefore('.lSSlideOuter');
});
```

Then the `overflow: hidden` property didn't affert the controls and I could use CSS to move them outside. Worked like a charm.